# Kubectl codepipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, kubectl, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-eks

I am getting **"Response Status: 401 Unauthorized"** error while deploying kubectl via codebuild. Can someone help?

**Logs snippets:**

I0804 12:13:45.711701      43 round_trippers.go:383] GET https://54E5332D7DAA77A8A685714EE1677CF8.sk1.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com/openapi/v2?timeout=32s 
I0804 12:13:45.711716      43 round_trippers.go:390] Request Headers: 
I0804 12:13:45.711723      43 round_trippers.go:393]     Accept: application/com.github.proto-openapi.spec.v2@v1.0+protobuf 
I0804 12:13:45.711729      43 round_trippers.go:393]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/435f92c 
I0804 12:13:46.409919      43 round_trippers.go:408] Re**sponse Status: 401 Unauthorized** in 698 milliseconds

Codebuild

````
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    DependsOn:
      - CodeBuildPolicy
    Properties:
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: !Ref KubernetesDockerImage
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        EnvironmentVariables:
          - Name: REPOSITORY_URI
            Value: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${EcrDockerRepository}
          - Name: EKS_CLUSTER_NAME
            Value: !Ref ClusterName
          - Name: EKS_KUBECTL_ROLE_ARN
            Value: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/<kubectl role>
      LogsConfig:
        CloudWatchLogs:
          GroupName: /aws/codebuild/aaa-test-pipeline
          Status: ENABLED
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InvokeKubernetesApply
      ServiceRole: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/<build>-cicd-CodeBuild'
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: !Sub |
          version: 0.1
          phases:
            install:
              commands:
                - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name ${ClusterName} --region eu-west-1
            build:
              commands:
                - kubectl apply -f .
      VpcConfig:
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId
        Subnets:
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet1Id
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet2Id
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet3Id```
````

Comment: does anyone has any answer for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you need to configure the environment using the same IAM entity that created the cluster.  The simple solution I found was to use the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY values from my admin user in my codebuild environment variables.  I'm sure a better long term solution is to recreate the cluster using the same role that you're running your build under, but I haven't tested that to be certain.

From AWS Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html

> When an Amazon EKS cluster is created, the IAM entity (user or role)
>   that creates the cluster is added to the Kubernetes RBAC authorization
>   table as the administrator (with system:master permissions. Initially,
>   only that IAM user can make calls to the Kubernetes API server using
>   kubectl. For more information, see Managing Users or IAM Roles for
>   your Cluster. Also, the AWS IAM Authenticator for Kubernetes uses the
>   AWS SDK for Go to authenticate against your Amazon EKS cluster. If you
>   use the console to create the cluster, you must ensure that the same
>   IAM user credentials are in the AWS SDK credential chain when you are
>   running kubectl commands on your cluster.